# If $X$ is a set of linearly independent vectors in a vector space $V$, then can vectors can be added to $X$ to give a basis for $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Normally, by the basis extension theorem, I would argue that this is possible, but I am not sure whether or not it will still be true if V is not finitely generated.

Comment: It's true. In order to prove it, use Zorn's lemma. (in the infinite dimensional case)

Answer (score 1):

If the global space is finite dimensional you have a $constructive$ proof using the Steinitz exchange lemma. If the global space is not finite dimensional it is still possible to prove the "basis extension theorem" but it is not constructive anymore and done by Zorn.